# Which software was used to produce this demo video?

Tags: video, animation, windows, shape

I'm wondering which software was used to create the demo video you can see in Piktochart's website.
The embedded Youtube video is this:

I know it is an infographics service (nothing related), but I wonder which tool or techniques they used to create the video stated above.
Or any alternative tools to generate such video type/kind

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Sigh.Impossible to say. It was probably something like After Effects, but could have been any number of things, including Resolve, Nuke, Blender, Natron, Flash, ToonBoom, or even Windows Paint, just to name a few. But knowing what the software was doesn't really help you: none of those packages comes with a "make me an animation" button. It's like knowing that the Mona Lisa was done with oil paints, it's not going to help you paint your own Rennaissance masterpieces is it?

If you want an animation done, just hire an animator for heaven's sake.